# How can I fix cannot find derive macro `Deserialize` in this scope?

Tags: rust, serde

I ran this code on my previous desktop and it worked fine:

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    bar: i64,
}

fn main() {}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
serde = "1.0"
```

but now I see

```
error: cannot find derive macro `Deserialize` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:1:5
   |
2  | #[derive(Deserialize)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: unused import: `serde::Deserialize`
  --> src/main.rs:2:10
   |
1  | use serde::Deserialize;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default
```

What can cause the issue? I'm using Rust 1.33.0.

Comment: You should add enable serde derive macros by adding the following to you cargo.toml
`[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }`